# OData Model not loaded?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am using an OData model in my SAP UI5 application. I do the following:

```
var oView = this.getView();
this._oModel = oView.getModel();
```

which I thought loaded the model and allowed me to access whatever I needed to inside the model. However whenever I try to get a property using `getProperty(path)` it returns undefined. I know the path is correct because I used it elsewhere in my application and it worked okay. The model I am using is named "metadata.xml" if that helps.

Comment: You will have to provide some more code to understand the cause of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation provided by SAP talking about OData services (I assume v2), you might find your answer there. Since you are using `getProperty()`, "you can only access single entities and properties with these methods. To access entity sets, you can get the binding contexts of all read entities via a list binding." Therefore you may want to a `read()` of the entity set first and then use the results of this read to access whatever property you want.

Link to doc: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2.html